# Rbac rules with Kubebuilder

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubebuilder

My probelm is that i am trying to use the `unstructured.Unstructured` type to create a deployment as such:

```
// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=stable.resource.operator.io,resources=resource,verbs=get;list;watch;create;update;patch;delete
// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=stable.resource.operator.io,resources=resource/status,verbs=get;update;patch
// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=apps,resources=deployments,verbs=get;list;watch;create;update;patch;delete
// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=apps,resources=deployments/status,verbs=get;list;watch;create;update;patch;delete
func (r *ResourceReconciler) Reconcile(req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {

    ctx := context.Background()
    log := r.Log.WithValues("resource", req.NamespacedName)
    instance := &stablev1.Resource{}
    // your logic here

    if err := r.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, instance); err != nil {
        log.Error(err, "unable to fetch Resource")
        // we'll ignore not-found errors, since they can't be fixed by an immediate
        // requeue (we'll need to wait for a new notification), and we can get them
        // on deleted requests.
        return ctrl.Result{}, ignoreNotFound(err)
    }
    // your logic here
    u := &unstructured.Unstructured{}
    u.Object = map[string]interface{}{
        "name":      "name",
        "namespace": "namespace",
        "spec": map[string]interface{}{
            "replicas": 2,
            "selector": map[string]interface{}{
                "matchLabels": map[string]interface{}{
                    "foo": "bar",
                },
            },
            "template": map[string]interface{}{
                "labels": map[string]interface{}{
                    "foo": "bar",
                },
                "spec": map[string]interface{}{
                    "containers": []map[string]interface{}{
                        {
                            "name":  "nginx",
                            "image": "nginx",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    u.SetGroupVersionKind(schema.GroupVersionKind{
        Group:   "apps",
        Kind:    "Deployment",
        Version: "v1",
    })
    err = r.Create(context.Background(), u)
    log.Error(err, "unable to get object")
    log.V(1).Info("reconciling")
    return ctrl.Result{}, nil

}
```

My understanding is that I have specified the rbac rules, my operator should be able to create said Deployment, but I am still getting the error:

```
the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
```

All the examples I have seen are based of using the actual deployment type, I cant find anywhere where there is an example of doing this with type unstructured, am i missing something?
Just to save time, I have tried:

- Applying the clusterroles manually
- Given the operator cluster-admin
- used both make run and make deploy (obviously after running make manifests etc..)
- The roles generator is working
- I have started a new project to make sure me playing around with env is not the cause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So seperatley from what the docs stated at https://godoc.org/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client when you define the type unstructured.Unstructured you need to set the namespace and name in the metadata field as such:

```
u.Object = map[string]interface{}{
        "metadata": map[string]interface{}{
            "name":      "name",
            "namespace": "namespace"},
        "spec": map[string]interface{}{
            "replicas": 2,
            "selector": map[string]interface{}{
                "matchLabels": map[string]interface{}{
                    "foo": "bar",
                },
            },
            "template": map[string]interface{}{
                "labels": map[string]interface{}{
                    "foo": "bar",
                },
                "spec": map[string]interface{}{
                    "containers": []map[string]interface{}{
                        {
                            "name":  "nginx",
                            "image": "nginx",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

otherwise unstructured client reads it as cluster scoped resource deployments, which does not exist

Comment: Yes, documentation is definitely buggy. the unstructured method GetNamespace() is explicitly using "metadata" field to reach its value: https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured/unstructured.go#L233 
:)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had been struggling with this for about a week